# Can I use the $store syntax directly on an object's property?

Tags: svelte

I have an object with a `Writable` property. Is there a way to use the `$store` syntax directly with `object.property`, or am I going to have to give the store its own name?

```html
<script lang="ts">
    export let motor: Motor;
    //  {
    //      profile: Writable<string>
    //  }

    console.log($motor.profile)   // nope
    console.log(motor.$profile)   // nope
    console.log($(motor.profile)) // nope

    let { profile } = motor;
    console.log($profile);        // sure
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to use the $store syntax directly with object.property. You will have to give the store its own name.

Comment: Relevant issue: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4079